ID a movie set in small town about two daughters whose mother is institutionalized

I saw this movie on sundance channel around 2006.
Set in a small town, looked like upstate NY, set in the 1950s-early 60s.
A family of 4. Two young daughters (5 & 8?), troubled mom is bipolar, gets institutionalized midway through the movie.

The daughters are preoccupied with their parents' unhappiness and with angels. In the end one of them drowns in the river behind their house and ascends with an angel.
I thought this was the Bolger sisters, but IMDb doesn't list it as them. Both young girls are great actresses and resemble the Bolger sisters at that age.

Angela (1995)

The ten year-old Angela and her little sister Ellie move to an old house in the countryside with her parents Mae and Andrew. Their mother has mental illness and has just left an institution and her husband tries to keep the dysfunctional family together. Angela is an imaginative disturbed girl that might have inherited the illness of her mother and is obsessed by purification to get rid of her sins; and has visions of the fallen angel Lucifer and the Virgin Mary. She leads her little sister in her paranoia and uses a circle of toys and dolls to protect them against evil. They have a crazy neighbor that Angela believes is an angel and she asks the woman how to find the way to heaven. When Mae returns to the institution, Angela becomes uncontrollable in her quest to heaven.





wow thats it! thank you very very much, youve made my weekend!

@dax If you think this is the correct answer, please consider to mark it as accepted (next to the up/down arrows).
